# How to extend timeout when waiting for citrus async action to complete?

Tags: integration-testing, citrus-framework

I'm using citrus to test a process that invoke a callback after performing several steps.
I've got the following sequence working:

- -> httpClient kicks process
- <- SUT answers OK
- <-> Several Additional Steps
- <- SUT invokes httpServer
- -> httpServer answers OK

I'm now trying to make it more generic by using the citrus async container to wait for the SUT invocation in // to the Additional Steps execution.

- async(

  - <- SUT invokes httpServer
  - -> httpServer answers OK
    )
- -> httpClient kicks process
- <- SUT answers OK
- <-> Several Additional Steps

The problem I'm facing is that after the last additional steps executes the async container does not seem to be waiting long enough for my SUT to invoke it. It seems to be waiting maximum 10 sec.

See below the output and the code snippet (without additional steps to make it simple)

```
14:14:46,423 INFO  port.LoggingReporter|
14:14:46,423 DEBUG port.LoggingReporter| TEST STEP 3/4 SUCCESS
14:14:46,423 INFO  port.LoggingReporter| 
14:14:46,423 DEBUG port.LoggingReporter| TEST STEP 4/4: echo
14:14:46,423 INFO    actions.EchoAction| VM Creation processInstanceID: 3543
14:14:46,423 INFO  port.LoggingReporter| 
14:14:46,423 DEBUG port.LoggingReporter| TEST STEP 4/4 SUCCESS
14:14:46,530 DEBUG      citrus.TestCase| Wait for test actions to finish properly ...
14:14:47,530 DEBUG      citrus.TestCase| Wait for test actions to finish properly ...
14:14:48,530 DEBUG      citrus.TestCase| Wait for test actions to finish properly ...
14:14:49,528 DEBUG      citrus.TestCase| Wait for test actions to finish properly ...
14:14:50,529 DEBUG      citrus.TestCase| Wait for test actions to finish properly ...
14:14:51,530 DEBUG      citrus.TestCase| Wait for test actions to finish properly ...
14:14:52,526 DEBUG      citrus.TestCase| Wait for test actions to finish properly ...
14:14:53,529 DEBUG      citrus.TestCase| Wait for test actions to finish properly ...
14:14:54,525 DEBUG      citrus.TestCase| Wait for test actions to finish properly ...
14:14:55,525 DEBUG      citrus.TestCase| Wait for test actions to finish properly ...
14:14:56,430 INFO  port.LoggingReporter| 
14:14:56,430 ERROR port.LoggingReporter| TEST FAILED StratusActorSSL.SRCreateVMInitGoodParamCentOST004 <com.grge.citrus.cmptest.stratus> Nested exception is: com.consol.citrus.exceptions.CitrusRuntimeException: Failed to wait for nested test actions to finish properly
at com.consol.citrus.TestCase.finish(TestCase.java:266)
```

Code snippet

```
        async()
        .actions(
            http().server(extServer)
                .receive()
                .post("/api/SRResolved")
                .contentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8")
                .accept("text/plain,application/json,application/*+json,*/*"),
            http().server("extServer")
                .send()
                .response(HttpStatus.OK)
                .contentType("application/json") 
        );



    http()
        .client(extClientSSL)
        .send()
        .post("/bpm/process/key/SRCreateVMTest")
        .messageType(MessageType.JSON)
        .contentType(ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON.getMimeType())


    http()
        .client(extClientSSL)
        .receive()
        .response(HttpStatus.CREATED)
        .messageType(MessageType.JSON)
        .extractFromPayload("$.processInstanceID", "processId");

    echo(" processInstanceID: ${processId}");
```

Answer (score 0):

another update... hopefully this might help other citrus users...

I finally implemented the behaviour I wanted, using the parallel citrus container as shown below. Nevertheless, I'll let this question open for few days as this does not answer my initial question...

```
        parallel().actions(
        sequential().actions(
            http().server(extServer)
                .receive()
                .post("/api/SRResolved")
                .contentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8")
                .accept("text/plain,application/json,application/*+json,*/*"),
            http().server("extServer")
                .send()
                .response(HttpStatus.OK)
                .contentType("application/json") 
        ),
        sequential().actions(
            http()
                .client(extClientSSL)
                .send()
                .post("/bpm/process/key/SRCreateVMTest")
                .messageType(MessageType.JSON)
                .contentType(ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON.getMimeType())

            http()
                .client(stratusClientSSL)
                .receive()
                .response(HttpStatus.CREATED)
                .messageType(MessageType.JSON)
                .extractFromPayload("$.processInstanceID", "processId"),

            echo("VM Creation processInstanceID: ${processId}")

        )
    );
```

The more I think about it, the more I believe this is a bug as when using async (as described above) I'm expecting the async part (and thus the test) to continue until the timeout given on the http server (in my case 60 sec) will expire or an expected request is received from the SUT and not after an arbitrary (10 sec) delay following the end of the non-async part of the test case unless I missed something about the async container features & objectives.